# @Override Method does not override from it's superclass

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-imagebutton

I just Started on learning java for our thesis.

Why does `@Override` Method does not override from it's superclass

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View home = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        //ImageButton
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)         
        home.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton)  
        home.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        button2.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        return home;
    }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
        int viewId = v.getId();
        switch (viewId)
        {
            //if imagebutton1 is clicked
            case R.id.imageButton1:
                Intent newActivity  = new Intent(HomeFragment.this.getActivity(), Tilapia.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);
                break;

            //button2
            case R.id.imageButton2:
                Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(HomeFragment.this.getContext(), Crab.class);
                startActivity(newActivity2);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

i don't know why i'm having this error. please help.

Comment: I would guess because your fragment is not an OnClickListener? You're passing `this` to `setOnClickListener` (with a cast), but your class definition states it only extends Fragment, and does not implement the interface `OnClickListener`

Answer (score 3):

Add `OnClickListener` implementation to fragment like:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not override `onClick()` method because onclick is not method of Fragment. 
`onClick()` is abstract method of `View.OnClickListener` interface. To override `onClick()` method, you have to implement interface `View.OnClickListener`.

e.g.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

}
```